# Latex : Images are not appearing in the LaTex documents

Tags: graphics, pdftex

I can see this is a common question. However, I dont find a solution to my problem. I write my master thesis in LaTex, and the images are not appearing in the pdf document when I compile. It does not throw any errors as well, so I have difficult time..

**This is my document class and packages;**

```
\documentclass[
11pt, % The default document font size, options: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt
oneside, % Two side (alternating margins) for binding by default, uncomment to switch to one side
english, % ngerman for German
singlespacing, % Single line spacing, alternatives: onehalfspacing or doublespacing
%draft, % Uncomment to enable draft mode (no pictures, no links, overfull hboxes indicated)
%nolistspacing, % If the document is onehalfspacing or doublespacing, uncomment this to set spacing in lists to single
%liststotoc, % Uncomment to add the list of figures/tables/etc to the table of contents
%toctotoc, % Uncomment to add the main table of contents to the table of contents
%parskip, % Uncomment to add space between paragraphs
%nohyperref, % Uncomment to not load the hyperref package
headsepline, % Uncomment to get a line under the header
%chapterinoneline, % Uncomment to place the chapter title next to the number on one line
%consistentlayout, % Uncomment to change the layout of the declaration, abstract and acknowledgements pages to match the default layout
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\textcolor{blue}{\arabic{footnote}}}
\usepackage{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font by default

%\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex} % Use the bibtex backend with the authoryear citation style (which resembles APA)
%\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}

%\addbibresource{example.bib} % The filename of the bibliography

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} % Required to generate language-dependent quotes in the bibliography

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images
\graphicspath{{Figures/}} % Location of the graphics files
```

**This is what I did to display an image;**

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering     %%% not \center
    \subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{./Unet.PNG}}
    \caption{Unet Architecture!!}
    \label{fig:Unet}
\end{figure}
```

Much appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: if you don't get an image there would be a message in the log. You don't need ` \subfigure{`  presumably you are using pdflatex (not latex-dvips which can not input png files)

Comment: Where exactly is `Unet.PNG` I've never seen a document where `./` was necessary for an image

Comment: Unet.PNG is on the same folder that contains .tex file

Comment: I removed dot (.) and put it like this:     /Unet.png               yet doesnt work.

Comment: My code below works in my **main.tex** but not with the **chapter1.tex**. "\begin{figure}[h!]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{/Figures/Electron}
  \caption[Execution time]{Execution time} 
 \label{fig:Execution time}
\end{figure} "

Comment: Apperas to me more like a syntax problem. // I suggest to prepare two most simple documents, one reflecting your main, a second reflecting your chapter1. Try just to include the path and display, no color, blindtext and whatever. // Start with a version which can not fail, i.e. put the .PNG into the same directory as main and chapter1. Then start moving it to a different folder and make both files work again. // Perhaps it turns out that it should read "Unet.PNG" or so. The package's manual should also tell you.

Comment: if yo have a leading / then that means the file is st the root of the file system it is probably not there. also you must surely have had an error message about the missing file. you already have Figures on the path do just use {Electron}

Comment: I downloaded **Masters/Doctoral Thesis LaTeX templates**. Where chapters are in a **different folders**. Usually everything compile correctly. Such as equations, references etc. But only problem is with the images. Do you think that makes the problem?